# Modern PHP Book - Clearification about "use" and "require" when using Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm currently reading [Modern PHP Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491905018) and I'm a little confused since in Chapter 2 the author talks about Namespace and he keeps saying import when he refers to the "use". In fact he states the following...

> *TIP*
>   You should import code with the `use` keyword at the top
>   of each PHP file, immediately after the opening `<?php` tag or...

The way I understand Namespace is that the `use` keyword references the namespace of the class but it doesn't import it and you still need to use `require` or `include` to import the actual class, correct?

I'm I correct when I say that when using namespace without auto-loading you will need to use `require` or `include` to import your classes?

Thanks

Comment: Without autoloading you would still need to require/include your code. Yes

Comment: You're correct. But imho autoloading is the way to go current times. Take also a look here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use autoloader, such as composer, you do not need to `import` or `require` PHP files (you only load autoloader file, which actually does all that for you). If you have no autoloader, you have to load files using `import` or `require`.

Then, after FILE is loaded, you can use `use` statements to do actual work with name-spaced items, such as classes, interfaces or traits.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm not sure why he makes that statement then since he only mentions `autolading` once before the statement but nothing formal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct. The `use` keyword in PHP merely *aliases* a namespace, in that it does what a *symlink* (on a *nix system) or *shortcut* (on a Windows system) would.

If you read the manual about [PHP namespace basics](http://php.net/language.namespaces.basics) you'll see that namespaces can be analogous to a filesystem where class/interface/constant/function names can be divided up into folders in order to prevent name-clashes.

If you read the manual section on [Namespace Importing](http://php.net/language.namespaces.importing) you'll see that when we refer to **importing** in PHP it actually means to create a shortcut of one name to another name (in fact the shortcut analogy above is taken right from the manual)...

> This is similar to the ability of unix-based filesystems to create symbolic links to a file or to a directory.

So, while confusing, the `use` keyword in PHP does not attempt to load (or `include`) the actual file containing the namespace, but rather just creates an alias for given namespace(s).

---

This may be very different use of the word **import** than you may be used to in other languages, where **import** can mean to load the actual file or package, but in PHP it's important to understand that importing a namespace has nothing to do with *autoloading* or *including* files. They are two separate concepts in PHP.

Importing a namespace is so that you can refer to `\fully\qualified\namespace\MyClass` as simply `MyClass` inside your namespace rather than having to use the FQN every single time (*hence the shortcut analogy*).

Autoloading, is for including the actual classes in PHP when they get used in code.

So there's a definite disconnect between the two concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned a *Chapter 2* in a *book*, I'm going to assume that you are still learning PHP, yes?

The use of `use` is to shorten namespaced classes to their root so that if you have some long namespaced class like

```
org\shared\axel\web\framework\connection\pipeline\impl\StopExecutionException
```

that needs to be instantiated with

```
new org\shared\axel\web\framework\connection\pipeline\impl\StopExecutionException();
```

You can use `use` to refer only to the root unnamespaced class

```
use org\shared\axel\web\framework\connection\pipeline\impl\StopExecutionException;
...
throw new StopExecutionException();
```

Keep in mind that you still need to have the class's code in your script, so you either include/require that manually by using `include` or `require`, or register autoloaders (see `spl_autoload_register`).
What that does is you define how your namespace maps to your source code's directory structure.

What others here refer to as `composer` is a package manager that includes an autoloader. At this stage, I personally think it's better to put off learning about this until you have a good grasp of the basics.

Comment: Yes I'm fairly new to PHP but I have been exposed to autoloading and composer already since I have been playing around with the Laravel framework. Thanks

Comment: That is correct. A lot of new concepts are used in the PHP/Laravel world.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an autoloader then `use` can be used to pull a Trait

## Trait file

```
namespace Blah;
Trait Foo {
    protected $somevar;
}
```

## Class file

```
Class Bar {
    use \Blah\Foo; // autoloaded
}
```

Otherwise, `use` is used to indicate that you want to either load a given class or alias that class as another

```
Class Foo {

}

use \Foo as Bar;
Class Something extends Bar {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, that helps.